# Access denied on hello world custom module

Tags: 8, routes, users

I installed Drupal 8 on a Debian VPS server.
Some installed themes don't work; some themes do work.

After I created a simple *Hello World* module and tried to access its page, I got an *Access denied* error.

These are the files I created for the module.

#### hello_world.info.yml

````yaml
name: Hello World
type: module
description: 'A basic Drupal 8 Hello World Module.'
package: Custom Modules
version: 1.0
core: 8.x

### hello_world.routing.yml

```yaml
hello_world_settings:
  path: '/hello/world'
defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::
myCallbackMethod'
  _title: 'Hello World'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
````

#### hello_world/src/Controller/HelloWorldController.php

```php
/**
* @file
* Contains \Drupal\hello_world\HelloWorldController.
*/
namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;
/**
 * Provides route responses for the hello world page example.
 */
class HelloWorldController {
  /**
  * Returns a simple hello world page.
  *
  * @return array
  * A very simple renderable array is returned.
  */
  public function myCallbackMethod() {
    $element = array(
      '#markup' => '<p><b>Saying Hello World in Drupal 8 is cool!</b></p>',
    );
    return $element;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Trying to access the page as an Admin?

Comment: Either way it does not work. Access denied for both!

Comment: A less frustrating habit is  just copying another modules routing.yml. No risk of typos.
Or generate new modules via drush generate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is with the indentation of the `hello_world.routing.yml` file. Simply change the indentation of it to:

```
hello_world_settings:
  path: '/hello/world'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::myCallbackMethod'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And the *Access denied* issue should be solved. The indentation of YAML file is  important, in Drupal 8. It should be as follow:

- `path`, `defaults`, and `requirements` should be indented by 2 spaces
- `_controller`, `_title`, and `_permission` should be indented by 4 spaces

Comment: This saved more wasted hours. Should've searched for this sooner.

Comment: in PHPStorm symfony plugin could warn you about proper yml indentation.

Comment: In Drupal 9.4.5 my route with `_permission: 'access content'` did not work but replacing with `_user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'` did work. Dont know why!