# Access Denied when visiting my custom route

Tags: routes

I have a custom module with machine name "mymodule". The *mymodule.info.yml* file looks like this:

```
name: My module
type: module
description: 'My first drupal module'
core: 8.x
```

Then I have a *src/Controller/FirstController.php* which looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Defines FirstController class.
 */
class FirstController extends ControllerBase {

/**
 * Display the markup.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Return markup array.
 */
    public function content() {
        return [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
        ];
    }

}
```

Finally, I have *mymodule.routing.yml* that looks like:

```
mymodule.content:
  path: '/mymodule'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\FirstController::content'
    _title: 'My first route'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

When I go to the url */mymodule*, I get Access Denied.
How can I fix the permission denied?

I saw a similar issue [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201808/access-denied-on-hello-world-custom-module) but the answer does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you clear cache after fixing the indentation of your *mymodule.routing.yml* file?

Comment: several times I did. For some reason it still does not work.
I also changed the path to '/nothingworks', cleared cache and when I visited I saw page not found. If I again visit /mymodule I get the access denied message